# Каким образом хранить в БД PostgreSQL ссылки на файлы?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, файлы

Изначально планировал хранить файлы непосредственно в БД, но как выяснилось это не лучшая идея. Прочитал о том что в БД должны храниться только ссылки на файлы.
Отсюда вытекает несколько вопросов:
1) Поле какого типа целесообразней использовать?
2) Каким образом связать файлы с бд, и соответственно сохранять ссылку и подтягивать файл?

Comment: Не существует принципиального запрета на хранение содержимого файлов прямо в БД (кстати, где вы прочитали, что это невозможно/неправильно?) Целесообразность такого подхода, зависит от многих обстоятельств, в том числе размеров файлов и характера контента. Уточните о каких файлах идет речь в вашем случае.

Comment: @cridnirk Растровые изображения в высоком разрешении

Comment: В таком случае хранение в виде внешних файлов полностью оправдано.

Comment: @cridnirk при получении контента такого файла всегда возникает лишний RTT + подвохи со стороны проксирующего языка, если в нем нет поянтия поточной обработки (весь файл приходится грузить в оперативку). Поэтому это no-no подход, который по умолчанию запрещен и может быть разрешен только в случаях необходимости.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

в бд обычно хранится не ссылка на файл, а просто его айдишка, если нужно хранить имя - в mysql - varchar(255), в постгрес - аналоги.

поскольку вам не нужно хранить весь путь к файлу, то вы можете ограничить поле длиной имени файла. А если вы храните просто айди файла - ну... вы просто делаете числовое поле достаточной длины для хранения миллионов или миллиардов файлов

ваш код соответственно подставляет путь к каталогу и айдишку/имя файла в нужном месте.

либо, если вам нужно сохранить имена файлов в тайне, чтобы пользователь не перебирал файлы или не угадывал имена, храните хэш, либо, чтобы сделать уникальные для каждой сессии айдишки,  передавайте хэш скрипту, который читает файл и выдает его в браузер, при этом ссылка от одного пользователя не будет работать  для другого.

@cridnirk прав, хранить или не хранить файлы в бд - зависит от проекта.  На хайлоаде, как правило, не стоит. Для компактных небольших сайтов, особенно если вы не хотите разбираться с хранением файлов, путями, а просто перекидывать бд туда-сюда  - возможно. Например, нет у вас времени и сил наладить нормальные бэкапы  и т.д., но есть несколько серверов бд - сделали репликацию - и у вас готовый бэкап файлов. (дико костыльно, имхо, но для всех разные решения)

Не относится к вопросу, но дополню по требованию из комментов: Отстающие по разным интервалам реплики можно сделать для восстановления: отставание одной реплики на 15 минут / а другой на 24 часа  - дает вам некоторую свободу маневров в случае катастрофических delete/drop  и т.д.

Наличие полей status, created, updated позволяет, как правило, не обращаться к этим репликам, поскольку в правильной архитектуре записи удаляются только вручную/автоматически по прошествии года и более. Вместо удаления проставляется статус deleted, проставляется поле updated, таким образом вы можете легко найти изменившиеся записи. Скриптам не дается право на delete.

Comment: Репликация - это ни в коем случае не бекап!

Comment: @Мелкий иногда ее так используют, и это работает для восстановления БД, это не только балансировка нагрузки.

Comment: С реплики можно снимать бекап, реплика может даже штатно отставать от мастера на заданную величину, реплика много чего может, но бекапом быть она не может. Hot stanby для быстрого восстановления при падении первичной базы - да, бекапом - нет. А если на проекте столько данных, что некуда бекапить базу - то уж явно файлы будут храниться не в ней, а в чём-нибудь более подходящем.

Comment: если на проекте столько данных, что некуда бэкапить базу или файлы, то это не проект, а фигня какая-то.

Comment: Вот именно. Потому и не надо писать, что репликацией можно заменить бекапы. Нельзя. Бекапы обязаны быть, делаться регулярно и регулярно же должна проверяться возможность из этого бекапа восстановиться.

Comment: @Мелкий если у тебя все данные в бд и тебя только они интересуют, и ты можешь накатывать их туда-сюда-обратно с реплик - это - бэкап. Я сказал уже, что для разных систем и подходов это может быть и костылем и подходящим решением.

Comment: Прохлопали в коде приложения какой-нибудь ненужный `delete`. Он, естественно, отреплицировался в штатном режиме. Ваши действия?

Comment: как можно прохлопать в коде ненужный delete? разные пользователи с правами на удаление на что нужны? и в принципе, delete/drop в коде недопустим. проставляется статус deleted, физическое удаление - через неделю/год, допустим, dba протупил. восстанавливаемся с остатющей реплики. Никакой код приложения в принципе не должен удалять данные из базы. Никогда. Только отлаженные для этого скрипты. Поэтому в каждой таблице должен быть  `enum status ('Active', 'Blocked', 'Deleted')`  - кроме таблиц со стастистикой, конечно. там по дате можно удалять

Comment: Как-как, shit happens. Не delete, так update какой-нибудь неудачный. Сюрпризы незапланированные рано или поздно, но будут. Уже появилась _отстающая_ реплика, замечательно. Откуда она появилась и почему необходимость настройки отставания не отражена в ответе?